# How do you get multiple addresses to one customer?

Tags: database, street-address

I cant work out how you get multiple addresses to one customer, for example. Any ideas on how to implement this?

Thanks

Comment: One table for customers, with a primary key.  A second table for the addresses, with a foreign key to the first table.  *[Even if these terms don't mean much to you, google them and learning how to use them will form a fundamental basis of your relational data knowledge.]*

Comment: I did do that, but it doesnt seem right, im not sure if it can be identified that way

Comment: Give example data that you think can't be modelled that way.  We can't mind read ;)  with the two table system many addresses can refer to the same customer => Each customer has many addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Use a foreign key in the addresses table

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
(
C_Id int NOT NULL,
other_stuff whatever,
PRIMARY KEY (C_Id),
)

CREATE TABLE Addresses
(
 A_ID int NOT NULL,
 C_ID int NOT NULL,
 other_stuff whatever,
 FOREIGN KEY (C_Id) REFERENCES Customers(C_Id),
 PRIMARY KEY (A_ID)
)
```

This can be used to implement a **one-to-many** relationship.

For example if you have George the `Customer` with `C_ID=55` then if you wanted to give George a new address then you would insert an entry into the addresses table with the value of 5 as C_ID.

```
insert into addresses (C_ID,blah,blah) values (55,blah,blah)
```

and then if you wanted to get all of George's addresses you would say:

```
select * from addresses where C_ID=55
```

If that didn't make sense, this here has pictures http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships/

Comment: You really should give the addresses a primary key too.